Installing Tomcat Certificate for WebSphere Application to Enable Secure Communication with Tomcat Server Endpoint
I need an assistance with certificate installation. My Websphere application unable to hit the tomcat server endpoint gives an certificate error. I have applied the certificate onto tomcat server.
I have a linux server, which has two users. (TOMCAT) and (WEBSPHERE).

TOMCAT USER

has a profile which is basically a server endpoint running.
I applied certificate on tomcat server by below steps.

SAN File
[ req ]
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
req_extensions = req_ext
prompt = no

[ req_distinguished_name ]
CN = server1.corp
OU = Manufacturer
O = XYZ
L = xyz_lang
ST = xyz_lang
C = UK

[ req_ext ]
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[ alt_names ]
DNS.1 = server1.corp
DNS.2 = server2.corp

Generate a new private key and certificate using the SAN configuration:
openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -days 1460 -keyout PROD.key -out PROD.crt -config san.txt

Create a new PKCS12 file from the key and certificate:
openssl pkcs12 -export -in PROD.crt -inkey PROD.key -out PROD.p12 -name PROD

Convert the PKCS12 file to a JKS:
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore PROD.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore PROD.jks

import to cacerts:
keytool -import -alias PROD -file PROD.crt -keystore ${JAVA_HOME}/lib/security/cacerts

NOTE
After the above .jks file is generated I added it into conf/server.xml along with keystore password, The tomcat endpoint is returning the payload which works fine. But problem comes when websphere application which hits the tomcat endpoint gets a below error.
Below is the error in my websphere application.
    2024-10-06 16:39:48,537 ERROR https://server1.corp:8443/personal/servlet/JSService; nested      exception is: 
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.jsse2.util.h: PKIX path building failed:      java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target.

I tried to add the same .jks file into the websphere application from websphere console but then websphere application doesn't start.
Any help would be highly appreciated.
